# Some songs are skipped over/broken on my iPhone; how can I find these?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, music

Sometimes when I go to play a song on my iPhone, it skips over it entirely and goes onto a song after it in the list.

The same happens when I try and play it in iTunes directly from the device - it gets a exclamation-mark-circle icon to its left when I try and play.

The songs have all been copied on by drag/drop from MP3 folders, so I suspect the copy process didn't completely properly.  Is there a way I can find all these songs so I can re-copy them?  (Trying to copy the entire album over again creates duplicate entries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this, [thanks to Galley from iLounge!](http://forums.ilounge.com/itunes-mac-pc/242332-how-isolate-missing-tracks-exclamation-mark.html)

1. Create a standard playlist called "Not Missing".
2. Drag your entire library into that playlist. Missing tracks cannot be copied to a playlist.
3. Create a smart playlist called "Missing" where:

   - Playlist - is not - Not Missing
   - *(additional to this post)*  Media type - is - Music

You now have a playlist which contains only your songs with the dreaded exclamation mark, and you can re-add them from your original source.

Answer (score 1):

There's a script to create a list of broken links on Doug's Applescripts called [List MIA's](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=listmias) :

"This script checks your entire iTunes library for missing (and presumed "dead") tracks–those that iTunes is unable to associate with a file and which are listed in iTunes with a "!"– and creates a text file listing these tracks by Artist - Album - Song Name which you can view using TextEdit."

Once you have a list, you can remove the dead tracks with another script [Super Remove Dead Tracks](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=removedeadsuper) and then use the list to figure out which tracks to re-import.

Answer (score -2):

On your iphone, tap on music.
Swipe left or right on a song, album or artist and a delete button will appear.
Delete whichever item you don't like.

Comment: Nigel, thanks for your comment, but that doesn't identify the songs which have this problem. You can only tell when you go to play them, and they don't play.